# Nginx - Localhost port is lost when clicking on anchor links

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm using Docker to run nginx on macOS to serve static files on `http://localhost:8080`.

When clicking on an anchor link, the port is being lost.

For example, clicking on `<a href="/foo">` will link to `http://localhost/foo` instead of `http://localhost:8080/foo`.

My nginx config is:

```
server {
  listen               80 default_server;

  server_name          _;

  root                 /var/www/root;
  index                index.html index.php;

  location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
  }

  error_page 404 /404.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

The directory structure of `/var/www/root` is:

```
├── foo
│   └── index.html
├── bar
│   └── index.html
└── baz
    └── index.html
```

However, when changing:

`try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;`

to:

`try_files $uri/index.html $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;`

the anchor links link correctly.

However, the following does not work:

`try_files $uri/ $uri $uri.html =404;`

What is going on exactly?  Is there a way to exclude `$uri/index.html` from `try_files` and have the anchor links preserve the port?

## Update

This works, but I'm not quite sure why.

```
if (-d $request_filename) {
  rewrite [^/]$ $scheme://$http_host$uri/ permanent;
}

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
}
```

Comment: Did you see this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519136/prevent-nginx-to-remove-the-port - I've had plenty of trouble here, but the other way. Leaving the port on when I don't want it.

Comment: @dgig, I had not seen it, but their solution works for me as well.

Comment: oh great then. glad it worked.

Comment: @dgig, Now to find out why ;-)

Comment: When I've tested various options that others reported to be successful, it first wasn't working. I had to clear the cache of the site (e.g. by using Developer Tools -> Network -> [x] Disable Cache) to finally see the successful redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the Dockerfile but I'm assuming you run the container with a port mapping of `8080:80`. However, nginx is probably still sending the Host header with port 80 and the anchor tag uses that host given how the base URI is calculated:

> User agents must calculate the base URI according to the following precedences (highest priority to lowest):
>
> 1. The base URI is set by the BASE element.
> 2. The base URI is given by meta data discovered during a protocol interaction, such as an HTTP header (see [RFC2616]).
> 3. By default, the base URI is that of the current document. Not all HTML documents have a base URI (e.g., a valid HTML document may appear in an email and may not be designated by a URI). Such HTML documents are considered erroneous if they contain relative URIs and rely on a default base URI.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-BASE

---

For development, it sounds like running the container with `8080:8080` should work. For production you might wanna set the appropriate `server_name` or Host header via an envvar.

Comment: Your assumption of `8080:80` was correct.  That makes perfect sense now.  Changing to `8080:8080` works nicely with: `try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;` (after changing the `listen` directive as well). Thank you!